# On Tab Click Clear the textbox value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page in Which there are four tabs. Each tab has some functionalities. Each tab has its own ID like for the first tab, tabid is 0 and for the second tab tab Id is 1 like that.

tabId 1 has customer creation details. My requirement is, Suppose I click on TabID 1 and fill the all information about customer creation and do not click on customer creation button,and Clicked on other tab suppose tabID 2.Then I need to get all the values of tabID 1 Cleared when I get back to it.

I am using this code to display different tab by clicking on it.

```
 function selectTab(tabid) {

        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs({
                show: function () {
                    var selectedTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
                    if (selectedTab == '1' || selectedTab == 1) {
                        alert(document.getElementById('<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>').value);
                        document.getElementById('<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>').value == '';
                        alert(document.getElementById('<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>').value);
                        document.getElementById('<%= txtLastName.ClientID %>').value == '';
                        document.getElementById('<%= txtDOB.ClientID %>').value == '';
                        document.getElementById('<%= txtMailLocation_AddressLine1.ClientID %>').value == '';
                    }
                    $("#<%= hdnSelectedTab.ClientID %>").val(selectedTab);
                },
                selected: tabid
            });
        });
    }
```

When I click on tabID 1 I am able catch  it my this code is not working.

```
document.getElementById('<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>').value == '';
```

showing same alert message.
SUppose txtFirstName has value 'kumod' then after this line still alert same value
Please help me how this problem will solve i need this in my project.

Comment: okay there might be same ids used multiple times. This seems to me.

Comment: <%= txtFirstName.ClientID %> - What does it return? and do you have same id input field in your html?

Comment: It's ruby syntax to show the values like echo in Php.

Answer (score 1):

Try jquery here may be helpfull for you.

```
function selectTab(tabid) {

        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs({
                show: function () {
                    var selectedTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
                    if (selectedTab == '1' || selectedTab == 1) {
                        $('#'+'<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>').val('');
                        $('#'+'<%= txtLastName.ClientID %>').val('');
                        $('#'+'<%= txtDOB.ClientID %>').val('');
                        $('#'+'<%= txtMailLocation_AddressLine1.ClientID %>').val('');
                    }
                    $("#<%= hdnSelectedTab.ClientID %>").val(selectedTab);
                },
                selected: tabid
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is working fine but can you give me code how clear the dropdownList in this code.

Comment: which dropdownList please share the html code and mentioned in it.

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSalutation" Width="60px" CssClass="ddlstyle" runat="server"
                                                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSalutation_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                                                          </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: $("#ddlSalutation").html("");

Comment: its not working ......it is not able to clear the value..please give me other solution

Answer (score 0):

mention and the form id  with in the tabs and use reset to clear the data of the form fields in side the tabs. this will reduce the code set for doing the same you mentioned above .

```
$("#form"+tabid).reset();
```

like this

```
function selectTab(tabid) {

    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            show: function () {
                $("#form"+tabid).reset();
            },
            selected: tabid
        });
    });
}
```